# Asynchronous method with large data taking 100% CPU

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I developed a desktop winforms application with the following processes:

1. `HttpListener` that keeps listening. There can be more than 300 concurrent incoming requests per minute
2. Here will send a http POST request using `HttpClient` to a cloud server and gets a integer response. The response is 0 and this value will be updated into the database using `EntityFramework` indicating that the current data is processed.
3. There is also an async void method with parallel task (let's call it method B) that continously checks the database if there is a data with value 0. If it's found then the method B will send a http POST request to the cloud server `HttpClient` to check if the process has finished or not. If finished then the method B will update the database with value 1.

With small request accepted by `HttpListener` (let's say 10 per minute) this application works very well. But it gets stuck `not responding` with 100% CPU load if it receives hundreds of request per minute. I can't figure it out which method causes this issue. It can be the `HttpListenerWrapper` or method B.

These are the code snippet

1. `HttpListener` class wrapper. It invoke `OnDataReceive`

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    StartListening();
});

private void StartListening()
{
    try
    {
        while (listener.IsListening)
        {   
            var result = listener.BeginGetContext((iAsyncResult) =>
            {
                if (!listener.IsListening)
                    return;

                var context = listener.EndGetContext(iAsyncResult);

                OnMessage(context);

            }, listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        RaiseError("Error listening. " + exception.Messages(), exception);
    }
}

protected void OnMessage(RequestContent request) => OnIncomingRequest?.Invoke(this, new IncomingRequestEventArgs(request));
```

2. When receiving

```
private async void HttpListenerWrapper_OnIncomingRequest(object sender, IncomingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(.....);
    var data = response....;
    ...
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        context.Add(data);
        var result = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

3. Looping process method B

```
private async void B()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                var data = context....ToList();
                var tasks = new List<Task>();

                foreach (var t in data)
                {
                    var task = Check(t);
                    tasks.Add(task);
                }

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}

private async Task Check()
{
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
    ....
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        context....;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use any of the [performance profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) tools?  If not, I would start there.

Comment: No. It's very hard to do this because the real data is in production computer and I have no access to it

Comment: Maybe because you are using an infinite loops, like `while (true)`?

Comment: @derodevil Surely you can produce a test dataset.

Comment: @J... No, I can't. The `HttpListener` should be called by 300 requests or more within a minute.

Comment: @derodevil I don't see how that prevents you from testing.

Comment: In the absence of profiling, this code is short enough that you can narrow things down by adding a Thread.Sleep(1) to each loop (one at a time, and then multiple if necessary) and observe the impact